# Recover bookmarks lost by FireFox Sync

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I think FireFox sync may have deleted all my bookmarks. I installed it on a new computer and selected the "Replace all data on this computer with my sync data" option. However, no bookmarks appeared, leaving me wondering if it has done the opposite and obliterated my bookmarks on the server.

Currently, I assume that my bookmarks are still stored on my other computers. Is there a way I can make a backup before Sync deletes them off those as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be to manually export your bookmarks with the builtin Bookmark Organizer (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>). That way you are safe if the sync goes wrong.

[image: Bookmark Organizer FF]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a message about intial sync taking up to 24 hours to complete when I first installed.

Check your profile directory for backups of the bookmarks file. Usually there is at least one.

Answer (score 0):

You're not crazy. This just happened to my boss when migrating bookmarks over to a new machine.

They all synced to his new machine just fine and then disappeared by the next morning from both machines.

What worked to fix this for me was to restore from the previous day's backup. Just click the `Restore` option as shown in @Nifle's answer and pick the previous day - or the day before if that doesn't work.